# Flash - Set maximum lines on TLFTextField

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, tlf

It is possible set an maximum number of lines to been showd on TLFTextField? So I have an text than I don't wanna that display all over the text, just the 3 first lines visibles. How can I configure that?

This is what I have yet:

```
         var myTLFTextField:TLFTextField = new TLFTextField();
         addChild(myTLFTextField); 
         myTLFTextField.x = 0;
         myTLFTextField.y = 0;
         myTLFTextField.width = _width
         myTLFTextField.height = 100;
         myTLFTextField.multiline = true;
         myTLFTextField.wordWrap = true;


         var myFormat:TextLayoutFormat = new TextLayoutFormat();
         myFormat.color = 0x336633;
         myFormat.fontFamily = "Arial, Helvetica, _sans";
         myFormat.fontSize = 24;
         myFormat.textAlign = TextAlign.LEFT;

        var textFlow:TextFlow = myTLFTextField.textFlow;
        var p:ParagraphElement = new ParagraphElement();
        var span1:SpanElement = new SpanElement();
        var span2:SpanElement = new SpanElement();
        var inlineGraphicElement:InlineGraphicElement = new InlineGraphicElement();
        var textLayoutFormat:TextLayoutFormat = new TextLayoutFormat();

        //Add graph
        inlineGraphicElement.source = drwCircle();
        inlineGraphicElement.float = Float.LEFT;

        //Add Text to the spans
        span1.text = "You can draw a happy face here ";
        span2.text = "if you like.as asdfads ad fas fadsf f asdfsdf asd sdafas dff asd adsf adsf adsf asf sadf asdf dfghjf  j  fhj fgffg hgfhj fg fgj fg jkb asdljk ljka jlkj asdjfh lajsdfh sd sdf asdfasd fdas asd fa sdfadsf asd adsf ad fadsf adsf ads fads fads f adsf asdf ";
        p.fontSize = 16;
        p.addChild(inlineGraphicElement);
        p.addChild(span1);
        p.addChild(span2);


        // Add Paragraph to text flow and update controller to display
        textFlow.addChild(p);
        textFlow.hostFormat = myFormat;
        textFlow.flowComposer.updateAllControllers();
```

Answer (score 1):

Luckily, using [TLFTextfield](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/text/TLFTextField.html) we have properties like `paddingTop` and `paddingBottom` of text and total `textHeight` in pixels. Knowing also the total `numLines` of text in the textfield, we can work out **how many pixels in height** the number of lines we want to show would take.

EDIT: I've noticed that for some rather *smalllish* widths of the textfield the `numLines` property doesn't hold the expected value... I don't know if this might be a BUG, but reading it before the calculation seems to fix it.

Try this (put these lines after all your code) :

```
//Pre read numLines property :(
myTLFTextField.numLines;

//how many lines you want to show
var numLines:uint = 3;

//set textfield height to the proportion between the total lines of text and
//the number of lines to show, taking into account the paddings of text
myTLFTextField.height = myTLFTextField.paddingTop + 
                        myTLFTextField.paddingBottom + 
                        (myTLFTextField.textHeight*(numLines+1)/myTLFTextField.numLines);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and this will work if I don't need to use any image on my "textfield", but I need to show an image align on the left of text and the text must be lesser than image, so with your solution this will cut my image too. But I guess I found a solution using TruncationOptions (that I just found it after a long hours ago), when I resolve that I'll post my solution. Thanks anyway, this will help for other cases :)

Comment: Great, glad you got it working! please post your solution as well for reference on TruncationOptions, I have never used it!

Answer (score 0):

You could mask the area with another clip to hide overflowing text.